# Is it possible to create a method that times an input method in Java?

Tags: java, time, reference

Is it possible to create a method that times another method by reference in Java?

I'm thinking of something like:

```
  int timeMethod(method myMethod) {
        long start = time
        run myMethod
        long end = time
        return end-start
     }
```

Comment: Thank you for all the great responses. I'll try out the solutions and then mark the best one. Also, thanks jigar joshi for formatting my question. I couldn't figure out why my 4 spaces wasn't working. I sound like an oscar winner, lol.

Comment: Your 4 spaces weren't working because you need a blank line before and after the code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I pass a Method as parameter of another method in java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6061049/can-i-pass-a-method-as-parameter-of-another-method-in-java)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can wrap your method call in a `Runnable` and time how long it takes the `Runnable` to run:

```
long timeMethod(Runnable myMethodRunner) {
    long start = System.nanoTime();
    myMethodRunner.run();
    return System.nanoTime() - start;
}
```

Then you can time your method as follows:

```
public void myMethod(...) {
    . . .
}

// later:

long timeInNanoSeconds = timeMethod(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        myMethod(...);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

AOP (aspectJ implementation) is what you are trying to reinvent, [here](http://www.christianschenk.org/blog/profiling-with-aspectj/) is quick google link describing the example

Answer (score 1):

You could use `System.currentTimeMillis();` for start and also do that for the end of the method and subtract the two like you mentioned.

```
public void timeExtensiveMethod() {
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    //do stuff 
    long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("Time taken: " + (end - start));
}
```

Note that not all the variables above are needed, they are just there to show the thought process.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing is as function pointer in Java (at least not exact function pointer). You can try eg Composition like:

```
int timeMethod(MyClass object) {
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        object.run();  //this class can implement a common interface and you program to interface not concrete implementation
        long duration = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
        return duration;
     }
```

Edit: +1 for AOP

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible, however I believe you should use a real profiler rather such a "silly" one.

You'll have to use [reflection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html) to invoke the method and [`System.currentTimeMillis()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis%28%29) or [`System.nanoTime()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime%28%29) to measure the elapsed time:

```
long measureMethodExecutionTime(Method method, Object object, Object[] args) {
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    method.invoke(object, args);

    return System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

No in java you cant pass method as parameter