# Java, pass non-static method into another method

Tags: java, methods, non-static

Here's the setup of my program. I want to tell the method checkerMethod which method to use, from either method1 or method2.

```
public Class executeCode{
World brave = new World();
brave.checkerMethod(Method method1);
}
```

My world class looks something like below.

```
public World{  //  changed to World from World() 

public World(){
//make world
}

public methodChecker(Method method){
//code involving using method1 or method2
//methods 1 and 2 are not static, so I would need to call this.method1()   
}

public void method1(){//method here}
public void method2(){//method here}

}
```

I have seen similar things, [here, for instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6061049/can-i-pass-a-method-as-parameter-of-another-method-in-java)

The solution above would not work obviously for passing non-static methods.

I have a feeling that if I rearrange things it may work, but I can't figure it out. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

Instead of passing methods and doing things reflectively, just pass in an invocable object that wraps the method and closes over `this`.

If all the methods you'll be passing are `void` zero-argument methods you could just use `java.lang.Runnable` thus

```
// final local variables are available to inner classes
final World current = this;

World.methodChecker(
    new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
        current.method1();
        // Or alternatively {World.this.method1();}
      }
    });
```

If you need to actually return a value or pass parameters, then
Guava's [`Function`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release12/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Function.html) is not a bad choice.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this in Java (without Reflection), but you can use a flag to mark which exact method to be executed:

```
public void methodChecker(boolean flag){
   flag ? method1() : method2();
}
```

Comment: Method class is already part of the reflection API, so probably author is expecting answer with reflection used.

Comment: I'm doing something similar now (I have more than two methods so I'm passing in a string and using a series of if statements), but it's not too pretty

Answer (score 0):

**Right way** is to consider redesign and make `methodN()` `Runnable` instead of method.

```
public class World {

public Runnable method1 = new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("1");
    }
};

public Runnable method2 = new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("2");
    }
};

public World() {
    //make world
}

public void methodChecker(Runnable method) {
    method.run();
}
}
```

It's certainly possible to keep `methodN()` as methods and run them using reflection. That is not a good practice, invocation is slower and you risk to face `SecurityException` on other environment. *Do not use reflection until you have no choice.* Solution is as follows:

```
public class World {

public World() {
    //make world
}

public void methodChecker(String method) {
    try {
        getClass().getMethod(method).invoke(this);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void method1() {
    System.out.println("1");
}

public void method2() {
    System.out.println("2");
}

}
```

The only difference with static methods invocation is that you pass reference to object to `invoke` method. In example with `Runable` there is no difference.