# How to pass methods as parameters in Android

Tags: java, android, methods, location

This may be a really stupid question or not even possible.

I am not sure if this would be called as a method, but going with this. How can I pass getCountryName(); as parameter? like show below;

```
public static String Utils(Something something){
    Geocoder geoCoder = new Geocoder(context, Locale.getDefault());
    List<Address> address = null;

    if (geoCoder != null) {
        try {
            address = geoCoder.getFromLocation(lat, lng, 1);
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (address.size() > 0) {
            return address.get(0).getCountryName(); // pass this as parameter (something)
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

and then call it like so,

```
Utils(getCountryName());
Utils(getCountryCode());
etc.
```

Comment: Try it you will get to know.

Comment: I have tried few things but there are really stupid like (Method name) but anyways these didn't work

Comment: You can pass method name which returns something(string,int etc). But to pass function you need to use functional programming features lamda expressions etc.

Comment: no need to check `geoCoder != null` - new never returns a null

Comment: @GyroGearless thanks will remove that. pushpendra can you show me please

Answer (score 2):

[This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6061100) helped me to do it. You can try it, too.

> Methods aren't first-class objects in Java, so they can't be passed as parameters. You could use wrap your method call in an annoymous class that extends e.g. the `Runnable` interface.

Answer (score 1):

You can use reflection.

e.g.

```
Method[] methods = Address.class.getMethods();
for (Method method : methods){
    if(method.getName().equals(param)){
        return (String) method.invoke(address.get(0));
    }
}
```

`param` would be of type `String` with value of the method you want to call.

EDIT:  Full example, using `getMethod(String)`

```
public static String Utils(String param){
    Geocoder geoCoder = new Geocoder(context, Locale.getDefault());
    List<Address> address = null;

    if (geoCoder != null) {
        try { 
            address = geoCoder.getFromLocation(lat, lng, 1);
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } 
        if (address.size() > 0) {
            Method method = Address.class.getMethod(param);
            if(method == null) return null;
            try{
                return (String) method.invoke(address.get(0));
            }catch(ReflectiveOperationException e){
                // Expected param maybe?
                return null;
            }
        } 
    } 
    return null; 
}
```

Comment: do I type Method[] methods = Address.class.getMethods(); this as the parameter?

Comment: No, your method signature would now look like `public static String Utils(String param)`

Comment: I am getting an error on this: method.invoke(address.get(0)); saying unhandled exception java.lang.exception.illegalstateexception ...

Comment: I assume you mean `IllegealAccessException`, that's just a throwable from the method invoke. Wrap it in a `try... catch`

Comment: Check edit, you can catch `ReflectiveOperationException` as 2 of the throwable inherit from it. There's also an `IllegalArgumentException` you should probably handle too.

Comment: Still getting an error on Address.class.getMethod(param); saying unhandled exception java.lang.noSuchMethodExpception

Comment: Handle that exception then

Answer (score 0):

In java that is the language that you are finally using. You can't pass a method or function as a parameter to a function. If you are able to use it, from Java 8 you have lambda expressions that are a kind of "anonymous" function. Try with that.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html

In this SO answer you have a very detailed guide. [Java Pass Method as Parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2186931/java-pass-method-as-parameter/25005082#25005082)

In that thread there are more info with some patterns if you can't use java8

Comment: Is there any other way to achieve this. I just want to be able to call one method but receive different values back. e.g. postcode, country name etc.

Comment: that's another question. You should implement one method for each value type. Maybe it's not a correct design having a method whose return values sometimes is a thing with a signifiance and in the next call the same method return a value whose mean is completely different...

Answer (score 0):

try this;

First define an Interface with the method you want to pass as a parameter

```
public interface Callable {
  public void getCountryName();
  public void getCountryCode();
}
```

Implement a class with the method

```
class Method_passing implements Callable {
  public void getCountryName() {
     //do your task
  }

  public void getCountryCode() {
     //do your task
  }
}
```

Invoke like that

```
Callable cmd = new Method_passing();
//This allows you to pass cmd as parameter and invoke the method call defined in the interface

public invoke( Callable callable ) {
  cmd.getCountryName(); //return name etc..
  cmd.getCountryCode();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could implement a getUtil function inside your adress class and then use identifiers to execute a function of your choice.

```
public class Address {
public static final int GET_COUNTRY_NAME = 1;
public static final int GET_COUNTRY_CODE = 2;

public String getUtil(int code){
    switch(code){
    case GET_COUNTRY_NAME: return this.getCountryName();
    case GET_COUNTRY_CODE: return this.getCountryCode();
    default: return null;
    }
}

private String getCountryName(){
    //do something
    return "";
}

private String getCountryCode(){
    //do something
    return "";
}}
```

and then define your function like

```
public static String Utils(int something){
Geocoder geoCoder = new Geocoder(context, Locale.getDefault());
List<Address> address = null;

if (geoCoder != null) {
    try {
        address = geoCoder.getFromLocation(lat, lng, 1);
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (address.size() > 0) {
        return address.get(0).getUtil(something);
    }
}
return null; }}
```

which would be called using

```
Utils(Address.GET_COUNTRY_NAME);
Utils(Address.GET_COUNTRY_CODE);
```